# How to join two selects

Tags: soql, joined-reports, sqlserver

I have these queries,

```
select ownerId from account
select firstname from user
```

How can I join them?
OR
How can I get the owner name from account table?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select owner.name from Account where ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT Owner.Name FROM Account WHERE ...`
Any time you've got a standard field which is a lookup, you can just remove 'Id' from the end and add '.Name' (or whatever other field you want). If you're dealing with a custom field (ending in __c), you can do the same with '__r.Name'